# How to dump a file name and size only to a text file in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd

I use the following command:

```
for %F in (*) do @echo %F %~zF
```

In order to create a list of filenames and size only. The output looks like so:

```
a.txt  21
b.txt  72
3.txt  73
```

Now my question is how do I dump it to a file? I tried to add `> filename.txt` at the end of the command, but it dumped only the last entry into the file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this:

```js
for %F in (*) do @echo %F %~zF> filename.txt
```

... is that the cmd interpreter is treating the redirect as part of the `@echo` statement, not as part of `for`.  You could use `>>` to append on each loop iteration, but that's inefficient.  That would essentially open, append, and close the file on each loop iteration.

A better solution would be to open the output file only once for writing, and keep it open until finished looping.  You can apply the redirect to the outer loop by enclosing the loop in parentheses.

```js
> filename.txt (
    for %F in (*) do @echo %F %~zF
)
```

or

```js
> filename.txt (for %F in (*) do @echo %F %~zF)
```

... whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like that:

```
>> filename.txt
```

More information about command line redirection:
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

> command > filename        Redirect command output to a file
>
> command >> filename       APPEND into a file

Comment: @benmeira, you welcome. Please mark it as an answer.